# How to install python if it doesn't exist from setuptools msi

Tags: python, setuptools

I wanted to package up my python installer so it would be easier to integrate into our WIX installer or other forms of product distribution. I was able to successfully build an exe (`python setup.py bdist_wininst`) and the msi (`python setup.py bdist_msi`) using setuptools, but what about the case where a user doesn't have python installed? Is there a way to add python itself as a dependency or otherwise have the msi/exe from setuptools install python if it is missing?

Answer (score 0):

The user of your `.exe` does not need to have python installed; that's beauty of creating binaries. All of the instructions that the client's computer needs to run the program are already in the `.exe`

Comment: Yes, I understand they don't need python installed to run the msi or exe, but it doesn't do them any good since there won't be any python installation to add the package to. The first step in the installer is to identify what version of python to use, but in the case of my test machine, python isn't installed so there aren't any versions to select.